# Github Actions - primary repository on push action always run

Tags: github-actions

I am having default repository `main` I wish to start an action against this repository only, but what happens: it is starting when any other repository does a push

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
```

Unless it reads main as all other branches changes, I cannot find any documentation on how it is with a default branch. It works fine on any other branches.

My goal is to trigger that job only when someone pushes code to `main.

Comment: Can you try putting the branch name inside `''` (`- 'main'`)? I have no idea if that makes any difference, but that's how I have it set up in my action and it works as expected.

Comment: The same effect. It probably works like this. I have added `branches-ignore - 'releases/**'` and this seems to be doing a job.

Comment: I'm very confused. First, are you talking about the main as the default branch, right? And you want this workflow to run only if the MAIN branch is triggered by a push.

Here's the link for the syntax documentation: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions

How it's triggered: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/triggering-a-workflow